# Java components not showing on JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a program which gives an overview of equipment. My problem is that the frame isn't displaying anything at all. Here is my code:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Start {

    protected static JButton exit;
    protected static JFrame main;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("running");
                Start mf = new Start();
                mf.init();
            }
        });
    }

    public void init() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        main = new JFrame("Main menu");
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main.getContentPane();
        main.setSize(750, 500);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(100, 50);
        exit = new JButton("Exit");
        exit.setPreferredSize(d);
        JLabel text1 = new JLabel("thingie");
        panel.add(exit);
        panel.add(text1);
        main.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I have been googling the issue, but most these issues are caused by people using `setVisible(true)` before they add their components, which I'm not doing. Hope you can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You didn't ad your panel to your main, so the components aren't on your JFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `Panel` to your `JFrame`. You can do so by: `main.getContentPane().add(panel);`

Comment: Now I only get the JLabel and not the JButton.

Edit: moved the main.getContentPane().add(panel); up just after setting default close operation, and got the button without further editing.